# How Do I Get UserName from .NetCore Identities by UserId from Razor Page?

Tags: .net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-identity

I need to get the UserName of post authors from the IdentityUser class in .Net Core 3.0 based on the UserId. The user id is a column in my posts table.

So far I have tried adding this

```sql
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@{var username = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(Model.Posts.Userid).Result.UserName}
```

Unfortunately this gives a runtime error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

I can't add scaffolding from the database to context class because when I did that the application would not run because any tables you add to the context is considered a duplicate of the default IdentityUser class.

I have tried going Google searches for stuff like ".net core get username by id" but all the examples I find only get the username or id of the logged in user. I want to get the username where the userid matches the author id in the posts table.

An even better solution would be to get the UserName from the PostsService class I made, but I don't know how to get foreign key values for stuff not in the ApplicationDbContext

Answer (score 0):

Don't use .Result when you can await it

```
@{var username = (await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(Model.Posts.Userid))?.UserName;}
```

Logic like this can be better placed in the controller as wel.

Comment: That does not work. It returns nothing for the user name.

Comment: I have changed my code a bit and it seems my problem now is I need to do more than one OnGet action. I have an OnGetAsync that gets the posts table data and then I need to get the user based on the userid in the post results.

Comment: I suspect you are right you need to do more in OnGet. U suspect Model.Posts.Userid is always null for all posts

Answer (score 0):

In controller , you can inject `UserManager<IdentityUser>` to get user's name :

```
private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync("975c96e2-85a4-46ac-8211-53c8ebae0e87");
    if (user != null)
    {
        var name = user.UserName;
    }
}
```

And why you will the post data in `OnGetAsync` method rather than an `OnPostAsync`method ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same question.  I wound up creating another field in my BlogPost Model to hold the Poster's UserName and used the first solution below to retrieve the username of the poster when the post is being created.  Then, With the Poster's name stored in the database with the post, it was easy to retrieve along with the other post info.